# How to get response after using POST method in Android

Tags: android, androidhttpclient

url is : http://localhost
method type : post
header : Content-Type:application/json, decode:2
data : xx

How can we achieve this in android??,and how do i get response from this ??
I saw that the Httpclient is deprecated

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: use volley http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using HttpUrlConnection

```
String Url, query;

    InputStream inputStream;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
    byte[] outputBytes;
    String ResponseData;
    Context context;
try{
            URL url = new URL(Url);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            outputBytes = query.getBytes("UTF-8");
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConnection.connect();

            OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            os.write(outputBytes);
            os.flush();
            os.close();

            inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            ResponseData = convertStreamToString(inputStream);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }


    public String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append((line + "\n"));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: My response would be a Json object though

Comment: It will give the response in json string and you can convert it into jsonObject

Comment: It says Unhandled Exception:java.io.IOException in url.openconnection

Comment: Check my edit i have added try catch code to handle exception

Answer (score 1):

```
 URL url = new URL("http://yoururl.com");
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstParam", paramValue1));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("secondParam", paramValue2));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("thirdParam", paramValue3));
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
writer.write(getQuery(params));
writer.flush();
writer.close();
os.close();
conn.connect();
```

..................................................................

```
private String getQuery(List<NameValuePair> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    for (NameValuePair pair : params)
    {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getName(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot,this helps,but how i add content type to this ??,i have a json object

Comment: getQuery will return string that contain your JSON after that u can extract it. If code helps you then you can mark as a answer thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpURLConnection if you dont want to use library otherwise you can use Volley also to make network call because volley make it easier to manage network call!
Thanks!

Comment: can i get an example,im new to android

Comment: https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-post-and-get-request-using-httpurlconnection/ for HttpURLConnection

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-volley--cms-23800   for volley

Comment: but i suggest you to use HttpURLConnection first thn you can try volley and other lib if my answer help you out please accpt my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use Retrofit Library, as Retrofit is faster and easier than other to load response from HTTP request.
visit, https://square.github.io/retrofit/

For Example, Here sample Json Object given,

```
{
  "title": "foo",
  "body": "bar",
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 101
}
```

Code:

```
public interface APIService {

    @POST("/posts")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<Post> savePost(@Field("title") String title,
                    @Field("body") String body,
                    @Field("userId") long userId);
}
```